# Angular 1.5 component css scoping with nested components

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-components

I'm trying to use angular 1.5 components to create a button group.

```
<button-group size="default">
   <my-button>Button 1</my-button>
   <my-button>Button 2</my-button>
</button-group>
```

But, it compiles to something like:

```
<div class="btn-group" ng-transclude>
   <my-button class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope>
      <button class="btn>Button 1</button>
   </my-button>

   <my-button class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope>
      <button class="btn>Button 1</button>
   </my-button>
</div>
```

So now my CSS scoping is all messed up:

```
.btn-group  > .btn:not(:first-child) {
     background: red; //<- doesnt work
 }
```

Basic example:

```
const buttonGroup = {
    bindings: {},
    transclude: true,
    template: myButtonGroupTemplate
  };
```

Comment: What is the question: How to modify your css to work or why it does not work or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes to your component

Something like that:

html

```
 <button-group size="default">
    <my-button class="awesome-class-btn">Button 1</my-button>
    <my-button class="awesome-class-btn">Button 2</my-button>
 </button-group>
```

css

```
.btn-group .awesome-class-btn > .btn:not(:first-child) {
     background: red;
}
```